# Change picture in Word no longer working correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I need to make a monthly report in Word. The graphs to put in to this report I generate in Excel and normally I then copy the graphs in Excel, go to Word to the graph of the previous month, right click and then select change picture - from clipboard. This used to work like a charm, but since two months most of the data from my graph isn't showing when I do this. The graphs end up looking like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to return to the previous way of working?

Comment: If you can do that — Can you upload a file with just that graph?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg Do you need the graph itself with all the data?

Comment: Yes, however you can put in fake data, that wouldn't matter. I just wanted to see the graph with the problem.